# Replace (substring) specific characters in a df Column R

Tags: r, substring

Hello I am looking to find a way to substring a column of a df.

```
Plot 
1. Ctr-M1 
2. Ctr-M2
3. CTR-W3
4. CTR-P-M20
5. M-1
6. W-15
```

the substring_plot should only include W or M
I tried something like this

```
 df$substring_plot = substr(df$plot,1,5,7)
```

Which does not work, I also understand why it does not work. I first thought I could just do this a few times until I am only left with the W and M, but that is very crude.

Does anyone have an idea how to get this done ?

Comment: Next time you post please also include the exact output you want so as to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sub`:

```r
df$plot_out <- sub("^.*([MW]).*$", "\\1", df$plot)
df

       plot plot_out
1    Ctr-M1        M
2    Ctr-M2        M
3    CTR-W3        W
4 CTR-P-M20        M
5       M-1        M
6      W-15        W
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(plot=c("Ctr-M1", "Ctr-M2", "CTR-W3", "CTR-P-M20", "M-1", "W-15"),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: That worked pretty much half way. I just need M or W not W-15 or M1 for example. And also for what ever reason plot_out still shows CTR-P-M20

Comment: If you really just want the letter, then use: `sub("^.*([MW]).*$", "\\1", df$plot)`

Comment: Thank you. I will look into sub() to figure out what you did there.